# Changing values in categorical column with condition in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, lambda

I have a list of values that I would like to check inside the pandas column. Meaning that if the new value will be different from this categorical values I will change them to some string. I am using `np.where()` with lambda function but it changes all the values I have. Can you assist a bit with fixing:

```
import numpy as np

lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']

df['col'] = np.where(lambda x: x not in lst, 'some string', df.col)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df['col'] = np.where(df['col'].isin(lst), 'some string', df.col)
```